# Confused about Join and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query

```
SELECT (T1.FirstDayOfMonth
      , T1.VehicleType
      , SUM(T1.Cost-T2.Cost)
      )
FROM (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth
           , VehicleType
           , [Cost] = Cost*Rate
      FROM fnCalculationData(@CalculationId1)
      GROUP BY FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType
      ) AS T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth
                    , VehicleType
                    , [Cost] = Cost*Rate
               FROM fnCalculationData(@CalculationId2)
               GROUP BY FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType
               ) AS T2 ON T1.VehicleType = T2.VehicleType
GROUP BY T1.FirstDayOfMonth, T1.VehicleType
```

But I realize I might need to filter my results on another field, `RegistrationTypeId` later on, so I add it to my selects:

```
SELECT (T1.FirstDayOfMonth
      , T1.VehicleType
      , T1.RegistrationTypeId
      , SUM(T1.Cost - T2.Cost)
        )
FROM (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth
           , VehicleType
           , RegistrationTypeId
           , [Cost] = Cost*Rate
      FROM fnCalculationData(@CalculationId1)
      GROUP BY FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId
      ) AS T1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT FirstDayOfMonth
                              , VehicleType
                              , RegistrationTypeId
                              , [Cost] = Cost*Rate
                         FROM fnCalculationData(@CalculationId2)
                         GROUP BY FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId
                         ) AS T2 ON T1.VehicleType = T2.VehicleType
GROUP BY T1.FirstDayOfMonth, T1.VehicleType, T1.RegistrationTypeId
```

But then this gives me the wrong cost value, (even If I dont include `RegistrationTypeId` in my main `SELECT`s `GROUP BY`) it changes row counts of my subselects and the result is wrong.

How can I get return this field without affecting the cost calculation?

Comment: Sample data please, with what you get and with what you expect.

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using? Seems like you need aggregated and detailed information at the same time and window functions can do the work here. Subselects too, of course.

Comment: Why all the parentheses?

Comment: TSQL? So many brackets... :)

Comment: The difficulty is that if each Vehicle Type can have multiple Registration Types then when you group by both it re-expands the Vehicle Type Grouping to a number of repeats of the vehicle type (one for each registration type). This would always do this so it depends on what is more important, having the Registration Type in it or maintaining the original cost value and row count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to include *all* the `GROUP BY` keys as `JOIN` keys:

```
select T1.FirstDayOfMonth, T1.VehicleType, T1.RegistrationTypeId, 
      (T1.Cost - coalesce(T2.Cost, 0)))
from (Select FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId, [Cost] = 
Cost*Rate 
      from fnCalculationData(@CalculationId1) 
      group by FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId
     ) t1 left join
     (Select FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId, [Cost] = 
Cost*Rate 
      from fnCalculationData(@CalculationId2) 
      group by FirstDayOfMonth, VehicleType, RegistrationTypeId
     ) t2
     on t1.FirstDayOfMonth = t2.FirstDayOfMonth and
        t1.VehicleType = t2.VehicleType and
        t1.RegistrationTypeId = t2.RegistrationTypeId;
```

You should not need the aggregation in the outer query.  You do need `coalesce()` in case there is no match in the second table.